# Different views/roles for administrator

Tags: plugins

I know there are plugins that manage user roles. Is there any plugin that manage user roles/view for the administrators in Wordpress?

There are some third party plugins that sometimes have their own menu. What i want to do is i want certain administrators cannot see these 3rd party menus. Is there such plugins?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [Admin Menu Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/admin-menu-editor/) which lets you directly edit the WordPress admin menu. You can re-order, hide or rename existing menus, add custom menus and **set visibility by capability**.